# error ServerManager' object has no attribute 'user_info' in pgAdmin 4, when trying to connect to a remote Server

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, userinfo, servermanager

When I try to connect to a remote database using pgAdmin 4 this error appears after having put all credentials info correctly

[image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KQGT.png)

Version of my pgAdmin is what appears in the image

[Version and other relevant info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkoKQ.png)

I have postgres 15 installed.

With pgAdmin i can connect to localhost databases w/o problem, but when I try remote no.

The remote database Im trying is one of a postgre sql course I'm doing, so I don't have so much privileges.

In any case, i can connect to this remote database in a bash console that I found on a website and also in Visual Studio Code.

So I suppose its a pgAdmin problem. Something in the configuration is not allowing?

I already tried to erase the Roaming folder with no effect in solving the problem.

I also installed the latest version available of pgAdmin.

What can I do?

Thanks in advance.